# Getting at grails.serverURL in a unit test?

Tags: grails, groovy, selenium, selenium-rc

I've created a test-type for selenium types, and now I'd like to use `grails.serverURL` as the base url for the system under test.

Using `ConfigSlurper` on `Config.groovy` doesn't pick up the environmentally-conditioned `grails.serverURL`, and `ConfigurationHolder.config` is null.

How do I access `grails.serverURL` in unit tests? (Really my custom-test-phase that runs like a unit test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `GrailsUtil.environment` to the `ConfigSlurper` constructor.

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper(GrailsUtil.environment).parse(new File('grails-app/conf/Config.groovy').toURL())
```